Looking for animated movie with owl smoking cigar and small bat
Like in title I'm looking for some old animated movie which I remember from past - I think it was around 1995 or something like this. I remember owl which always smoked cigar, and he had helper - little clumsy bat. Owl was always mean to that bat. They both was helping bad sorcerer (he was able to turn into dragon), who lived in big, dark castle.
About plot, there was princess, and that sorcerer wanted her. And of course there was some prince or knight that was fighting to rescue princess. Last thing I remember about it is the ending. Sorcerer was trying to change into dragon, but good guy killed him when he was half way. Sorcerer turned into rock as dragon with only human head.

Do you think it was also released around '95? Was it American?

@poepje I think it could have been released earlier couse when I was looking for it on IMDb I found something with very similar way of animation : this. And I watched it in Europe.

Yay, at least I found it : Happily Ever After :) It's about Snow White, and what happened after Evil Queen has died. It's from 1990.

The Evil Queen is dead and Snow White is on her way to see the 7 dwarves when Lord Maliss, the Queen's brother, sees her in the looking glass. He attacks her in the form of a dragon, taking Snow White's prince to the Realm of Doom. Enlisting the aid of the dwarves' cousins, Snow White must embark on a quest to save her true love.

See Owl top left with said cigar...

